# How to get sale order line description on Odoo web service API?

Tags: php, api, web-services, odoo

I am trying to get the sales order description items using the odoo webservice with laravel, How can I get this information?

Comment: I managed to get the information like this :


    $items = $odoo->where('origin', '=', $customer->sonumber)
    ->get('account.invoice.line');

Answer (score 0):

you will call "search_read" or "read" method of odoo and you will get all the data of odoo

Example:

```
$models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'res.partner', 'search_read',
                    array(array(array('is_company', '=', true),
                    array('customer', '=', true))),
                    array('fields'=>array('name', 'country_id', 'comment'), 'limit'=>5));
```

model name: 'res.partner'
Domain : array(array(array('is_company', '=', true),
                        array('customer', '=', true)))
fields: list of fields which fields you want.

i hope it will be help

Thanks